# How to find the sum of this array in CPLEX (concert C++)?

Tags: c++, arrays, cplex, ilog

I have written this code to find the sum

```
int sum=0;

for (i = 0u; i < n[k]; i++)
        {
            sum = sum + include[k][i];
        }
```

definition for include is as follows:

```
IloArray<IloNumVarArray> include(env, N_CONSIGNMENTS);

for (k = 0; k < N_CONSIGNMENTS; k++)
{
    include[k] = IloNumVarArray(env, n[k]);

    for (i = 0; i < n[k]; i++)
    {
        //if (i == k)continue;
        include[k][i] = IloNumVar(env, 0, 1, ILOBOOL);

    }
}
```

error I am getting is:

```
no suitable conversion function from "IloNumExprArg" to "int" esists
```

How to rectify this?

Answer (score 0):

After you have solved your model you can ask CPLEX for the value of your IloNumVars, something like:

sum = sum + cplex.getValue(include[k][i]);

but I can't be sure that I remembered the syntax correctly. There should be plenty of examples out there.

Comment: the sum is a part of the constraints though...so can't evaluate it after the model has been solved

Comment: But the sum cannot then be an int because the IloNumVars will not yet have a value until the model is solved. You will have to use something like an expression (IloNumExpr) to model the sum of those variables.